# Assuming AMD64 calling convention would be standard could Windows and Linux have shared code?

Tags: linux, assembly, compiler-construction, x86, x86-64

AMD64 has different calling conventions on Linux and Windows but imagine if they were the same would it be possible to have code share amongst them?

I know there is difference between COFF and ELF, and things like shared libraries are different (GOT vs whatever Windows does) and function names are of course also different.

Barring all this could it be possible? For example ARM has the same convention on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "share code". The can share the same C/C++ source code relatively easily, but it would be hard for them to share binary code because of the different executable formats. The difficulty of sharing the same assembly source code is somewhere in between.

Comment: Even with differing standard convention you can roll your own as long as you don't need to interoperate with other code.

Comment: If Windows and Linux were more similar, then they wouldn't be Windows and Linux. It's hard to know how far you are willing to stretch the hypotheticals, but it is clear that they are hypothetical, or better said contrafactual. If your question is whether you can share binaries between two OSs if they are sufficiently similar, then yes: it is possible to run some BSD binaries on Linux and vice versa, if they don't rely on extensions to the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The calling convention defines how parameters are stored in stack/registers, how return values are handled etc. If they were equal, code could be shared, even in binary form.

However, the code must not have any dependencies to a specific platform. For example the code cannot use syscalls for IO, but might use a platform specific library for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe codecs in specially crafted libraries.

But any binary (library or executable) links in some OS specific entry code, and when it does something non trivial (like purely stream processing codecs again) it interfaces to the OS. Those will be different.

For that same reason it is impossible to run BSD binaries on Linux (contrary to wrong comments). The BSD syscall is different, processing of parameters to the binary (csu/crt*) are different and some syscalls are inlined.

People get drunk on POSIX api simularities, but forget that POSIX is a *source* not binary convention.